# PHPWord Internal Server Error

Tags: phpword

I am trying to solve one issue from a very long time.. My PhpWord Document downloads properly in localhost but i do not get the exact output.. My word prints the  tag directly without make it strong. The same file when i run it on my test server i get internal server error 500.. Please help me out.. Below is the code

```
 function download($id, $letterName) {
    $a_json = array ();

        if(!$letterName)
            die(false);

        $this->getHtml();

        switch($letterName){
            case "Evaluation:Transfer":
                $query = "SELECT CONCAT(wrk.employee_name,'  ',wrk.employee_lastname) employee_name,
                br.branch_name new_branch,
                oldBr.branch_name old_branch,oldBr.branch_name branch_name,cde.department_name department_name,cd.designation_name designation_name,wrk.employee_id,DATE_FORMAT(ct.action_effects_from,'%d-%m-%Y') doj,ct.affected_ids affectedIds
                FROM employee_work_details wrk
                INNER JOIN company_branch br
                ON wrk.branch_id = br.branch_id
                INNER JOIN emp_branch_history brHist
                ON wrk.employee_id = brHist.employee_id AND brHist.effects_upto = DATE_SUB( wrk.branch_effects_from , INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                INNER JOIN company_branch oldBr
                ON brHist.branch_id = oldBr.branch_id
                LEFT JOIN company_designations cd
                ON wrk.designation_id = cd.designation_id
                LEFT JOIN company_departments cde
                ON wrk.department_id = cde.department_id
                INNER JOIN comp_transfers ct
                ON wrk.transfer_id = ct.action_id
                WHERE wrk.transfer_id = '$id' AND wrk.enabled=1 ";

                break;
            case "Evaluation:Promotion":
                $query = "SELECT CONCAT(wd.employee_name,' ',wd.employee_lastname) employee_name,desg.designation_name designation,
                oldesg.designation_name old_designation,cb.branch_name,cd.department_name,
                DATE_FORMAT(pro.action_effects_from,'%d-%m-%Y') effective_from,wd.employee_id,pro.affected_ids affectedIds,c.company_name
                FROM employee_work_details wd 
                INNER JOIN company_designations desg 
                ON wd.designation_id = desg.designation_id 
                INNER JOIN company_branch cb 
                ON wd.branch_id = cb.branch_id 
                INNER JOIN company_departments cd 
                ON wd.department_id = cd.department_id
                INNER JOIN company_details c
                ON c.company_id = '" . $_SESSION ['company_id'] . "' 
                INNER JOIN comp_promotions_increments pro 
                ON wd.promotion_id = pro.action_id 
                INNER JOIN emp_designation_history desHis 
                ON wd.employee_id = desHis.employee_id AND desHis.effects_upto = DATE_SUB(wd.design_effects_from,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                INNER JOIN company_designations oldesg ON oldesg.designation_id = desHis.designation_id 
                WHERE wd.promotion_id='$id' AND wd.enabled=1";
                break;
            case "Evaluation:Promotion come Increment":

                $query = "SELECT CONCAT(wd.employee_name,'',wd.employee_lastname) employee_name,desg.designation_name designation,
                oldesg.designation_name old_designation,pro.incremented_amount increment_percentage,sh.employee_salary_amount old_salary,s.employee_salary_amount new_salary,cb.branch_name,cd.department_name,
                DATE_FORMAT(pro.action_effects_from,'%d-%m-%Y') effective_from,wd.employee_id,pro.affected_ids affectedIds 
                FROM employee_work_details wd 
                INNER JOIN company_designations desg 
                ON wd.designation_id = desg.designation_id 
                INNER JOIN company_branch cb 
                ON wd.branch_id = cb.branch_id 
                INNER JOIN company_departments cd 
                ON wd.department_id = cd.department_id
                INNER JOIN employee_salary_details s
                ON wd.employee_id = s.employee_id
                INNER JOIN employee_salary_details_history sh
                ON wd.employee_id = sh.employee_id AND sh.effects_upto = DATE_SUB(s.effects_from,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                INNER JOIN comp_promotions_increments pro 
                ON wd.promotion_id = pro.action_id 
                INNER JOIN emp_designation_history desHis 
                ON wd.employee_id = desHis.employee_id AND desHis.effects_upto = DATE_SUB(wd.design_effects_from,INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                INNER JOIN company_designations oldesg ON oldesg.designation_id = desHis.designation_id 
                WHERE wd.promotion_id='$id' AND wd.enabled=1 ";
                break;
            case "Evaluation:Increment":

              $query = "SELECT CONCAT(w.employee_name,'',w.employee_lastname) employee_name,desg.designation_name designation, 
                        pro.incremented_amount increment_percentage,sh.employee_salary_amount old_salary,s.employee_salary_amount new_salary,
                        cb.branch_name,cd.department_name,w.employee_id,pro.affected_ids affectedIds,DATE_FORMAT(pro.action_effects_from,'%d-%m-%Y') effective_from,c.company_name
                        FROM employee_work_details w
                        INNER JOIN employee_salary_details s
                        ON w.employee_id = s.employee_id
                        INNER JOIN employee_salary_details_history sh
                        ON w.employee_id = sh.employee_id  AND sh.effects_upto = DATE_SUB(s.effects_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                        INNER JOIN company_designations desg 
                        ON w.designation_id = desg.designation_id 
                        INNER JOIN company_branch cb 
                        ON w.branch_id = cb.branch_id 
                        INNER JOIN company_departments cd 
                        ON w.department_id = cd.department_id 
                        INNER JOIN company_details c
                        ON c.company_id = '" . $_SESSION ['company_id'] . "' 
                        INNER JOIN comp_promotions_increments pro 
                        ON s.increment_id = pro.action_id 
                        WHERE s.increment_id = '$id' AND w.enabled = 1;";
                break;

            case "Offer:Confirmation":
                $query ="SELECT w.employee_id,CONCAT(w.employee_name,' ',w.employee_lastname) employee_name,w.employee_doj doj,des.designation_name designation,
                            dep.department_name department,DATE_FORMAT(s.effects_from,'%d-%m-%Y') effect_from,s.employee_salary_amount salary,CONCAT(w.employee_probation_period/30,' ','months') months,cd.company_name
                            FROM employee_work_details w
                            INNER JOIN employee_salary_details s
                            ON w.employee_id = s.employee_id
                            INNER JOIN company_designations des
                            ON w.designation_id = des.designation_id
                            INNER JOIN company_departments dep
                            ON w.department_id = dep.department_id
                            INNER JOIN company_branch b
                            ON w.branch_id = b.branch_id
                            INNER JOIN company_details cd
                            ON cd.company_id = '" . $_SESSION ['company_id'] . "' 
                            WHERE w.employee_id = '$id'";
                break;

            default:
                die("No Letter Found");

        }
        $result = mysqli_query ( $this->conn, $query ) or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));

        $letter = new letterTemplate($this->letterContent);

        $filename = str_replace ( ' ', '', $letterName );
        $PHPWord = new PHPWord ();
        $count =0;
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
            $affectedIds = $row ['affectedIds'];

            foreach ($row as $key=>$field){
                $letter->set($key, $field);
            }
            $section = $PHPWord->createSection ();


            if ($count >= 0)
                $letterContnt = "{$letter->output()}" . $section->addPageBreak ();

                else
                    $letterContnt = $letter->output();

                    $html_dom = new simple_html_dom ();
                    $html_dom->load ( '<html><body>' . $letterContnt . '</body></html>' );
                    $html_dom_array = $html_dom->find ( 'html', 0 )->children ();

                    $initial_state = array (
                    // Required parameters:
                    'phpword_object' => $PHPWord
            ); // Must be passed by reference.

                    htmltodocx_insert_html ( $section, $html_dom_array [0]->nodes, $initial_state );

                    $count++;
        }
        if($count==0)
            die("No Data Found. Unable to Generate Letter.");
            $letterName = preg_replace ( '/\s+/', '', $letterName );
        //  print_r ();
            $fileName = str_replace ( 'LTR', '', $letterName ) . '_' . $affectedIds . '.docx';


            $h2d_file_uri = tempnam ( " ", "htd" );




            $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter ( $PHPWord, 'Word2007' );

            $objWriter->save ( $h2d_file_uri );

            // Download the file:

            header ( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
            header ( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
            header ( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fileName . '' );
            header ( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header ( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize ( $h2d_file_uri ) );
            ob_clean ();
            flush ();
            $status = readfile ( $h2d_file_uri );
            unlink ( $h2d_file_uri );
            exit ();
            // Save File
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error_log file to see what the error is? If you are using xampp then it should be in 
C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log